# How to intsert quotation mark `'` into mariaDB using mysql-client?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am using mariaDB(Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.17-MariaDB, for osx10.10 (x86_64)) and `mysqlclient==1.3.6`.

I just want to insert a string into a varcharfield.

```
import MySQLdb
import json

conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='ng')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(INSERT INTO `current_table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '{name}');".format(name="Lily' dog"))

conn.commit()
```

but I always got a error like this:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's dog', NULL)' at line 1")
```

what should I do if I want to insert quotation mark by mysql-client?

Comment: `conn.escape_string("Lily' dog")`. Always escape your strings. Obligatory [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) link.

Comment: @Amadan after using `conn.escape_string("Lily' dog")`,  still a error exist: `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'s dog"\', NULL)\' at line 1')`

Comment: Please show how you used it (by editing the post and appending the new command).

Comment: @Amadan Awesome! after modify formater to `cmd = "update people set name=%s where id=%s" ` and `curs.execute(cmd, (name, id))`, it can be successfully inserted into database without `escape_string`. I just wondering why people always suggest using `format` instead of using `%s`

Comment: @Sinux - If you have found the answer why not post it as a answer to your own question - then it will be available for others to use in the years to come.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Sorry, a little busy at that time, have posted my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Amadan's comment, in [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html)(the site for preventing SQL injections), it suggest:

> Using the Python DB API, don't do this:
>
> ## Do NOT do it this way:
>
> ```
> cmd = "update people set name='%s' where id='%s'" % (name, id)
> curs.execute(cmd)
> ```
>
> Instead, do this:
>
> ```
> cmd = "update people set name=%s where id=%s"
> curs.execute(cmd, (name, id))
> ```

so in my situation, just modify the execute line to :

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO `current_table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, %s);"
cur.execute(cmd, ("Lily's dog"))
```

and this can avoid the error which quotation mark leads to.